# Como tornar este slideshow infinito?

Tags: javascript, jquery

É um carrossel que vai passando, mas a única forma que consegui fazer foi assim: quando chega no último slide, ele volta para o primeiro, fazendo uma espécie de "transição de retorno" ao início.

Questão: Gostaria que os slides ficassem em loop infinito. Que no final, o primeiro viesse empurrando o último, se é que me entendem. 
Caso fique alguma dúvida, por favor, comente que tentarei explicar melhor e editar a pergunta.

Código abaixo:

```js
$(function(){
 //número do slide atual (1 porque pega do primeiro e vai incrementando)
 var controller = 1;

 //identifica o número de slides (<li>)
 var numSlides = $('.carrossel .item').length;

 // tempo de transição
 var time = 600;

 //loop que gerencia a troca de slides
 setInterval(function(){
  //se o slide atual não for o último, anima para o próximo
  if(controller < numSlides){

   //animação do trilho para o próximo slide
   $('.carrossel').animate({
   'margin-left': '-'+controller*300+'px'
   }, time);

   //incrementa a var controller ao passar um slide
   controller ++;
  }
  //se o slide atual for o último, anima para o primeiro
  else{

   //zera o margin-left do trilho de slides (ul)
   $('.carrossel').animate({
   'margin-left': '0px'
   }, time/2);

   //volta o controller para 1
   controller = 1;
  }
 }, time+2500);
})
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 list-style: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-carrossel {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 10% auto;
 position: relative; 
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
 overflow: hidden;

}

.carrossel {
 width: 1000%;
 background: #fff;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}

.carrossel .item {
 float: left;
 width: 300px; 
 background: #2E9ABE;
 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-carrossel">   
    <ul class="carrossel">
     <li class="item">slide  1<img src="http://i.imgur.com/9uibBZz.png" /> </li>
     <li class="item">slide  2<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SN10FH8.png" /> </li>
     <li class="item">slide 3<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3Mgc4kt.png" /> </li>  
     <li class="item"> slide 4<img src="http://i.imgur.com/eeGWPqv.png" /> </li> 
     <li class="item">slide  5<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SN10FH8.png" /> </li>    
    </ul>   
  </div>
```

Comment: Gambiarras são válidas? Acho que tenho uma solução. :P

Comment: Sim, Inkeliz. rs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como é "rotativo infinito", tem como eliminar completamente o movimento do "trilho":

Na parte do HTML e do CSS demos uma "enxugada" eliminando elementos desnecessários, nos aproveitando destas características:

- Usando `inline-block` em um *container* com `white-space: nowrap` os elementos ficam todos em uma linha só, sem precisar de uma `div` extra;
- assim, o `overflow:hidden` esconde os slides a mais, deixando só o principal e o que está entrando no quadro;
- como consequência, podemos setar os slides com `100%` de largura, assim se precisar ajustar o layout, basta mudar a largura do `.container`;
- a classe `item` é desnecessária, pois podemos usar o seletor de filho `>*`.

Em seguida, vem a lógica do JS:

- A cada `intervalo` usamos o animate para mover o primeiro slide `100%` para a esquerda, deslocando sua margem;
- Usando o *callback* do animate (quarto parâmetro) definimos uma função que pega esse slide que acabou de sair da tela, e coloca ele no fim da lista, e zera a margem dele para a próxima volta;
- o *callback* usa `this`, de forma a funcionar com mais de um slider na mesma página (veja na demonstração a seguir).

Quem desloca nesta lógica é só o primeiro ítem, saindo de fato da tela e indo para o fim da fila. Não é uma cópia no fim da fila, e sim o ítem mesmo que muda de posição.

Eliminamos o conceito do trilho, aí seu carrossel ficou infinito de fato, pois não vem mais ao caso a quantidade de ítens.

Se mudar alguma coisa no layout e na quantidade, basta ajustar o HTML, e no máximo o CSS, ajudando muito no reaproveitamento do código para páginas geradas dinamicamente.

```js
$(function() {
   var duracao = 600;
   var intervalo = 2400;

   setInterval(function() {
      $('.carrossel>*:first-child').animate({'margin-left': '-100%'}, duracao, 'linear',
         function() {$(this).appendTo(this.parentElement).css('margin-left', '0');}
      )
   }, intervalo);
})
```

```css
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.carrossel {
   width:330px;
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
   background:#2E9ABE;
   list-style:none;
}

.carrossel>* {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}

.dois {               /* Só para demonstrar um segundo slider  */
   background: #c90;
   position:absolute;
   width:220px;       /* Largura diferente do primeiro         */
   left:350px;
   top:0;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="carrossel">
   <li>Slide 1<br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9uibBZz.png"></li>
   <li>Slide 2<br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SN10FH8.png"></li>
   <li>Slide 3<br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/3Mgc4kt.png"></li>
   <li>Slide 4<br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eeGWPqv.png"></li>
   <li>Slide 5<br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SN10FH8.png"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="carrossel dois">
   <li>Gato 1<br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1HTd.png"></li>
   <li>Gato 2<br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTin1.png"></li>
   <li>Gato 3<br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/87KH0.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Minha ideia foi a seguinte, lembrando que talvez não seja a melhor:

Se o `controller` for maior do que o número de `slide` ele joga o primeiro `slide` para o último:

```
$('.carrossel .item').eq(0).appendTo(".carrossel");
```

Porém, temos que fixar um `margin-left` para que isso funcione, isso irá obter o `width` necessário:

```
var width = $('.carrossel .item').eq(0).width();
```

Agora, precisamos que o carrossel entenda que o quarto elemento (agora penúltimo) esteja com o `margin-left` fixo de `width * 4`, melhor dizendo: `width * (numSlide - 2)`.

```
$('.carrossel').css('margin-left', '-' + ((numSlides - 2) * width) + 'px');
```

Agora está pronto.

A mudança no `animate`, no final, é apenas para dar compatibilidade nos dois casos (quando não esgotou e quando esgotou os slides), como não daria para o `controller` como multiplicador, passou a usar o valor atual do `margin-left` "somado" com mais `width`:

```
$('.carrossel').animate({
   'margin-left': ( parseInt($('.carrossel').css('margin-left')) - width ) + 'px'
}, time);
```

Sempre que acabar os slides, ele irá copiar o primeiro e jogar para o último e com a margin fixada anteriormente irá somar com o `width`.

**Resumindo:**

Quando chegar o último slide ele entrará num loop de `-1300px` para `-1500px` e sempre copiando o primeiro slide para o último. ;)

```js
$(function() {
  // Número do slide atual (1 porque pega do primeiro e vai incrementando)
  var controller = 1;

  // Identifica o número de slides (<li>)
  var numSlides = $('.carrossel .item').length;

  // Identifica o tamanho
  var width = $('.carrossel .item').eq(0).width();

  // Tempo de transição
  var time = 600;

  // Loop que gerencia a troca de slides
  setInterval(function() {

    // Se o slide não estiver "esgotado"
    if (controller < numSlides) {

      //incrementa a var controller ao passar um slide
      controller++;

      // Se o slide "acabar"
    } else {

      // Move o primeiro para o ultimo
      $('.carrossel .item').eq(0).appendTo(".carrossel");

      // Fixa a margem de ( (Total de slide) - 1 ) * Largura
      $('.carrossel').css('margin-left', '-' + ((numSlides - 2) * width) + 'px');

    }

    // Animação do trilho para o próximo slide
    $('.carrossel').animate({
      'margin-left': ( parseInt($('.carrossel').css('margin-left')) - width ) + 'px'
    }, time);

  }, time + 2500);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-carrossel {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carrossel {
  width: 1000%;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.carrossel .item {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background: #2E9ABE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-carrossel">
  <ul class="carrossel">
    <li class="item">slide 1
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9uibBZz.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="item">slide 2
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SN10FH8.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="item">slide 3
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3Mgc4kt.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="item">slide 4
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eeGWPqv.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="item">slide 5
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SN10FH8.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```